# Running "SQL" query for each comment box will speed down multi-level commenting system?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database-design

i am developing **multi-level** (comments and repelis) comment system using `php`.
all comments and repelis are in same database table.
in the function this system have to run 'sql' query for each comment box to generate them in correct order.
so, will this slow down strongly my system while handling thousands of comments.
here below is my function,

```
function getComments($row) {
    echo "<li class='comment'>";
    echo "<div class='aut'>".$row['author']."</div>";
    echo "<div class='comment-body'>".$row['comment']."</div>";
    echo "<div class='timestamp'>".$row['created_at']."</div>";
    echo "<a href='#comment_form' class='reply' id='".$row['id']."'>Reply</a>";
    $q = "SELECT * FROM threaded_comments WHERE parent_id = ".$row['id']."";
    $r = mysql_query($q);
    if(mysql_num_rows($r)>0)
        {
        echo "<ul>";
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($r)) {
            getComments($row);
        }
        echo "</ul>";
        }
    echo "</li>";
}
```

or i have another idea to put comments and repelis in tow tables. while comments displaying,
get all repelis data to Array and push them in to related comment box using `for loop` for that array.

which method will be best for this work. the best performance ?

Comment: It will run slowly. There is an overhead for executing a query and you will being executing potentially hundreds of queries. However the main alternative is the nested set model and this makes inserts slow (as you need to alter many other records), although you can maybe minimise that using a thread id, so you only need to alter the other records for the thread.

Comment: Another alternative is that if there is a fixed max number of levels of comments then you can do a join for each level. But it makes your script more complicated and suffers due to the max number of levels.